# Maintaining state of chekbox cheked in Asp Datagrid in different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datagrid

I am using Asp.net DataGrid  control to bind some Data, In datagrid I have one column in which Chekbox is placed. How I can maintain the state of Checkbox cheked on different Pages as when I move to next page in datagrid to view furthur records ,Previous values are refereshed. what I want to maintain its state on different pages like user can select some records from 1st page then some from 2nd page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you load your data dynamically?

Comment: Since ASP.NET is stateless, you're data is always lost unless you save it somewhere on postback.

Comment: Yes, I am fetching data dynamically, on second page records being fetched from the database.

Comment: You can make it work with jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that, you have to save your checked checkboxes anywhere on `next page` or `previouse page` click.

If you don't do that, you will allways loose your information about checked checkboxes because APS.NET ist stateless like @Complexity sayed bevore.

More information about stateless and statefull, you can find here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101337/whats-the-difference-between-stateful-and-stateless